# how can use count in sprig-data

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

imagine this senario, i have a class:

```
public class TOTO{

    private int Id;
    private Boolean bool1;
    private Boolean bool2;
    private Boolean name;

    //constructor
    //getters
    //setters

}
```

also i have a spring data repository:

```
public interface TOTORepository extends JpaRepository<TOTO, Long> {

    @Query( "SELECT COUNT(*),toto from TOTO toto where toto.bool1=false groub by name " )
    List<TOTO> getIncidentDepart();

}
```

the result i want to get is: number of objects grouped by name. another problem where i can store COUNT(*) variable in the abject level.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: the object TOTO has not a field where it can store the count number

Comment: @imsiimsi can you check my answer ?

Comment: Generally it's best to let Spring Data generate the query if possible. In this case, your problem is that you're trying to return two different results, which is simply not how *Java* works. Either separate the count and the main select into different queries or use `list.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate bean class (`TOTOGroupingByNameData`) and this needs to be populated from the `@Query` to get the result like below:

**TOTOGroupingByNameData Bean Class:**

```
public class TOTOGroupingByNameData {
  private String name;
  private Long   count;

  public TOTOGroupingByNameData(String name, Long count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count  = count;
  }
}
```

**Repository interface:**

```
public interface TOTORepository extends JpaRepository<TOTO, Long> {

   @Query(value = "select new TOTOGroupingByNameData(t.name, count(t)) from TOTO t where where t.bool1=false group by t.name")
   List<TOTOGroupingByNameData> findCountByName();

}
```

P.S: Assumed that name is `String` type, if it `boolean` like in your question change to `boolean` type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom contructor in your TOTO class and add a [Transient](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/api/org/neo4j/ogm/annotation/Transient.html) field to store the result of the count.

For example your TOTO class will be:

```
public class TOTO{

    private int Id;
    private Boolean bool1;
    private Boolean bool2;
    private Boolean name;

    @Transient
    private Long totalNumber;

   // constructor you will use in your query
    public TOTO(int Id, Boolean bool1, Boolean bool2, Boolean name, Long totalNumber){
       this.Id = Id;
       this.bool1 = bool1;
       this.bool2 = bool2;
       this.name = name;
       this.totalNumber = totalNumber;
   }

    //getters
    //setters

}
```

And the query would be like:

```
@Query( "SELECT new package.to.Toto(toto.id, toto.bool1, toto.bool2, toto.name, count(*) as totalNumber) from TOTO toto where toto.bool1=false groub by toto.name " )
    List<TOTO> getIncidentDepart();
```

With this approach remember to write the package to TODO class when instantiate the constructor.

Comment: thank you for the answer ...but i have to write new package.to.Toto.......

Comment: yes you must specify where the class is. I know it's not the most elegant solution, but this way you can do whatever you want! i used it a lot with complex query, that are not easy to handle with spring jpa.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [package.to.ListeDeControleDetailsMission] [SELECT new package.to.ListeDeControleDetailsMission(lm,count(*) as totalNumber) from com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm where lm.boolDepart=false GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart]

Comment: instead of package.to you have to write the actual package of ListeDeControleDetailsMission class. And write every single field you want to return in the constructor. As i did in the answer

Comment: wait...I will try

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission]. 
Expected arguments are: com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission, long 
[SELECT new com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission(lm,count(*) as totalNumber) from com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm 
where lm.boolDepart=false GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart]

Comment: thank you very much....i'm waisting your time but heres my repository: @Query( "SELECT new com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission(lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,count(*) as totalNumber) from ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm where lm.boolDepart=false GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart" )
    List<ListeDeControleDetailsMission> getIncidentDepart();

Comment: it gives an error agian:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, long [SELECT new com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission(lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,count(*) as totalNumber) from com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm where lm.boolDepart=false GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart]

Comment: i want to return just : the name of designation and the number .